# "Auth failed" in Eclipse EGit

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I have committed/pushed a project to a GitHub repository via Eclipse. However, when I try to push any changes to it I get the following error message:

```
Transport Error: Cannot get remote repository refs.
ssh://mmannila@github.com/.../project.git: Auth fail
```

I'm sure that I gave the correct pass phrase and URI during authentication, and I've tried looking for solutions. Eclipse points to the correct SSH folder, so this can't be a problem caused by a wrong directory reference.

Comment: Try doing with `http ://` link. Hope it works with that.

Comment: I tried an https link and it worked. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Happy coding..!!!

Answer (score 1):

I could push and pull through command line, but not in eclipse.

It could also be your ssh-keygen is new, the generated key starts with the headers:

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I think currently eclipse can't take this new kind of key.
Regenerate your ssh key by using command:

```
ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -b 2048
```

This will use the old way to generate the key:
it will starts with the headers:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
```

see more information on:

https://github.com/duplicati/duplicati/issues/3360

Then you can load the key again in eclilpse by using
Preferences -> Network connections -> SSH2, click "Add Private Key"
(still select your private key, even you already see the name in the list of private keys, because eclipse has to reload it)

Answer (score 0):

Makes sure Eclipse is loading the right private key.

Go to Preferences -> General -> Network connections -> SSH2
Then check the folder it has path set in `SSH home`.